# Accuracy doesn't change over keras training, loss barely decreases

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a neural network to solve picross (aka nonogram) puzzles on a 5*5 grid using keras. This would mean the network would ideally have multiple correct activations for each training case.

I've made a way to randomly generate the training data and initialized the neural network, but upon running it, the accuracy of the network never changes, and the loss only slightly decreases:

Epoch 1/100
100000/100000 [==============================] - 13s 133us/sample - loss: 1.6282 - acc: 0.5001

Epoch 2/100
100000/100000 [==============================] - 13s 131us/sample - loss: 1.6233 - acc: 0.5001

Epoch 3/100
100000/100000 [==============================] - 13s 132us/sample - loss: 1.6175 - acc: 0.5001

...

Epoch 99/100
100000/100000 [==============================] - 14s 136us/sample - loss: 1.4704 - acc: 0.5001

Epoch 100/100
100000/100000 [==============================] - 14s 136us/sample - loss: 1.4696 - acc: 0.5001

I'm running this using Jupyter notebook.

I've been told that using "binary_crossentropy" as a loss function is an ideal one for the problem, but I've no idea how to format the training data labels for this. Should it be a list of ones and zeros, or a list of numbers, or an array...?

The output layer is 25 neurons, each corresponding to a block on the 5*5 grid. They would have a correct activation of 1 or 0 depending on whether that block is empty or not.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.optimizers import SGD

network = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(750, activation=tf.nn.relu))
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation=tf.nn.relu))
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu))
network.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
network.compile(optimizer='SGD',
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
network.fit(scaled_x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=50)
```

I expected the accuracy to increase as the training goes by, even if only by a little, but the accuracy stays stuck at whatever value it starts off with, and the loss function only decreases a little bit.

Edit: The data given to the inputs of the neural network are the "hints", scaled down to be values between 0 and 1. Here is the code for the creation of the data:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

x_train = []
y_train = []

for m in range(100000):  #creating a data set with m items in it
    grid = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
    hints = [[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]]]

    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            grid[i][j] = random.randint(0,1)   #All items in the grid are random, either 0s or 1s


    sub_y_train = []
    for z in range(5):
        for x in range(5):
            sub_y_train.append(grid[z][x])

    sub_y_train = np.array(sub_y_train)
    y_train.append(sub_y_train)         #the grids are added to the data set first



    ##figuring out the hints along the vertical axis
    for i in range(5):
        counter = 0
        for j in range(4):
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                counter += 1
                if grid[i][j+1] == 0:
                    hints[0][i].append(counter)
                    counter = 0
        if grid[i][4] == 1:
            hints[0][i].append(counter+1)
            counter = 0


    ##figuring out the hints along the horizontal axis
    for i in range(5):
        counter = 0
        for j in range(4):
            if grid[j][i] == 1:
                counter += 1
                if grid[j+1][i] == 0:
                    hints[1][i].append(counter)
                    counter = 0
        if grid[4][i] == 1:
            hints[1][i].append(counter+1)
            counter = 0

    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(5):
            while len(hints[i][j]) != 3:
                hints[i][j].append(0)

    new_hints = []
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(5):
            for k in range(3):
                new_hints.append(hints[i][j][k])

    new_hints.append(5)

    x_train.append(new_hints)    #Once the hints are created and formalized, they are added to x_train


x_train = np.array(x_train)      #Both x_train and y_train are converted into numpy arrays
y_train = np.array(y_train)



scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_x_train = scaler.fit_transform((x_train))

for i in range(5):
    print(scaled_x_train[i])
    print(y_train[i])
```

Comment: What is your input data and in what representation you're giving it to the NN?

Comment: If multiple outputs can be 1 you should use `tf.nn.sigmoid` as activation, not softmax.

Answer (score 0):

Peteris was correct, it seems replacing the "softmax" activation function with "sigmoid" on the output layer of the network has now helped the accuracy steadily increase. Currently, the network is almost reaching a steady 95% accuracy. (Thank you so much, I've been trying to get this working for weeks)